# If loop is not getting executed when using timeout in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, timeout

I have a bash script which uses `curl` and `timeout`.

```
 for element in "${array[@]}"; do
     if timeout 2s curl -v "telnet://$element:8888"; then
      echo "'$element' connected" && break
     fi
 done
```

The script is not entering the if loop and I am getting following output:

```
* About to connect() to abc001 port 8888 (#0)
* Connected to abc001
* About to connect() to abc002 port 8888 (#0)
* Connected to abc002
* About to connect() to abc003 port 8888 (#0)
* Connected to abc003
```

The array has values:

```
abc001
abc002
abc003
```

Answer (score 1):

timeout: If the command times out, and --preserve-status is not set, then exit with status 124.  Otherwise, exit with the status of COMMAND.
The `if` will evaluate to true when the return value is 0.
When you change `curl..` into `echo curl...` it will execute the if-statement.
Perhaps you want something like

```
for element in "${array[@]}"; do
   if curl --connect-timeout 1 --max-time 2 --silent "$element:80" >/dev/null; then
       echo "'$element' connected"
   else
      echo "Connection with $element failed."
   fi
done
```

Comment: I am now getting a blank screen. The `if` statement has `telnet` in it as well  `if curl --connect-timeout 1 --max-time 2 --silent "telnet://$element:8888"`

Comment: telnet waits for input, my example is how to test hosts. Try without `telnet:://` and test what is happening without the max-time and only one `element` (not a loop).

Comment: I am getting msg - Connection with abc001 failed.when not using `telnet`